# Cannot Install SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, installation

I am trying to install SQL Server 2008 R2 on a Windows XP machine.

I am just trying to install Database engine services only, I get am getting an access denied error. Here are the key lines from detail.txt file. I don't know what this means or how to fix it,

```
2011-01-21 14:44:47 Slp: Configuration action failed for feature SQL_Engine_Core_Inst during timing ConfigRC and scenario ConfigRC.
2011-01-21 14:44:47 Slp: Access is denied
2011-01-21 14:44:47 Slp: The configuration failure category of current exception is ConfigurationFailure
2011-01-21 14:44:47 Slp: Configuration action failed for feature SQL_Engine_Core_Inst during timing ConfigRC and scenario ConfigRC.
2011-01-21 14:44:47 Slp: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied
2011-01-21 14:44:47 Slp:    at System.Diagnostics.ProcessManager.OpenProcess(Int32 processId, Int32 access, Boolean throwIfExited)
2011-01-21 14:44:47 Slp:    at System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessHandle(Int32 access, Boolean throwIfExited)
2011-01-21 14:44:47 Slp:    at System.Diagnostics.Process.OpenProcessHandle()
2011-01-21 14:44:47 Slp:    at System.Diagnostics.Process.get_Handle()
2011-01-21 14:44:47 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SqlEngine.SqlServerServiceBase.WaitSqlServerStart(Process processSql)
2011-01-21 14:44:47 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SqlEngine.SqlServerServiceSCM.StartSqlServer(String[] parameters)
2011-01-21 14:44:47 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SqlEngine.SqlServerStartup.StartSQLServerForInstall(String sqlCollation, String masterFullPath, Boolean isConfiguringTemplateDBs, Boolean isSlipstreamRunning)
2011-01-21 14:44:47 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SqlEngine.SqlEngineDBStartConfig.ConfigSQLServerSystemDatabases(EffectiveProperties properties, Boolean isConfiguringTemplateDBs, Boolean useInstallInputs)
2011-01-21 14:44:47 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SqlEngine.SqlEngineDBStartConfig.DoCommonDBStartConfig(ConfigActionTiming timing)
2011-01-21 14:44:47 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SqlEngine.SqlEngineDBStartConfig.Install(ConfigActionTiming timing, Dictionary`2 actionData, PublicConfigurationBase spcb)
2011-01-21 14:44:47 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SqlConfigBase.PrivateConfigurationBase.Execute(ConfigActionScenario scenario, ConfigActionTiming timing, ConfigBaseAction action, Dictionary`2 actionData, PublicConfigurationBase spcbCurrent)
2011-01-21 14:44:47 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SqlConfigBase.SqlFeatureConfigBase.Execute(ConfigActionScenario scenario, ConfigActionTiming timing, ConfigBaseAction action, Dictionary`2 actionData, PublicConfigurationBase spcbCurrent)
2011-01-21 14:44:47 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SqlConfigBase.SlpConfigAction.ExecuteAction(String actionId)
2011-01-21 14:44:47 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SqlConfigBase.SlpConfigAction.Execute(String actionId, TextWriter errorStream)
2011-01-21 14:44:47 Slp: Exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception.
2011-01-21 14:44:47 Slp: Source: System.
2011-01-21 14:44:47 Slp: Message: Access is denied.
2011-01-21 14:44:47 Slp: Watson Bucket 1 
 Original Parameter Values
```

Thanks in advance.

Bob

Comment: Are you using an XP user account that does not have a password? I remember having all sorts of install and configuration issues until I set an XP account password.

Comment: Thanks Marc, with your hint I finally figured out how to accept an answer. Often time, I don't get my answer from Stack Overflow. I might get it from another source, figure it out myself or just use a different solution to my problem. If I do find the answer, I try to  post it. There is nothing more frustrating that googling your problem finding the exact problem with no solution posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution that worked on another forum. Please see:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlsetupandupgrade/thread/ed4514fa-8d1d-4383-bbdf-fb06bfbad106/

This failure often is caused by a system or domain policy removing the SeDebugPrivelege security privilege from the administrator account running setup. Verify that the account running has this privilege.

Open Group Policy...
 Start | Run | Type: gpedit.msc | OK |
Navigate to
 Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\User Rights Assignment\Debug programs

The account through which we are trying to run the setup should be here ( besides the local admin on that machine). I included that here, restarted the server ( this is mandatory, gpupdate /force will not work) and ran the setup and it was successful this time.

SQL Server 2008 setup needs this privilege to start up the SQL Server process and listen to an event that signals back to setup that SQL Server successfully started.

Answer (score 1):

If you work with the DoD or many other government images they will often take away the User Right Assignment of Debug Programs as a security measure.  Make sure you give your accounts that need SQL access this right back.  This includes the account you do the SQL install with.

Answer (score 0):

It's a security problem. The Bottom-most error "Access is denied" tells you that. Barring getting lucky with a Google search, you'll need to put [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) on it and capture the actual Access is Denied to see what access is being denied *to*.

You'll have a raft of data, but my guess is it's probably trying to access a registry key it doesn't have permissions for.